# Partial order, well order and initial segment

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

I saw the following definition for initial segment in  https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs

> If $\leq$ is a partial order in a set $X$, then a chain $C\subseteq X$ is a subset C of
> X that is totally ordered by the order $S$ . Note that the empty set is a chain. If $C$
> is a chain in $X$ and $x\in C$, then we define
> $P(C, x) = \{ y\in C| y < x\}$.
> A subset of a chain C that has the form $P(C, x)$ is called an initial segment  $C$.

But in wikiproof ([https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Initial_Segment#:~:text=The%20concept%20of%20an%20initial,this%20concept%20as%20a%20section.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Initial_Segment#:%7E:text=The%20concept%20of%20an%20initial,this%20concept%20as%20a%20section.)), initial segment is defined as

> Let $(S,\leq)$ be a well-ordered set. Let $a\in S$.
> The initial segment (of S) determined by $a$ is defined as: $S_{a}:=\{b\in S:b\leq a∧b≠a\}$

Are these two definitions equivalent? One defines $\leq$ to be a partial order, and the other defines it to be a well-ordering.

Comment: They are equivalent in the context of a well-ordered set, which is always a chain.

Comment: The $S_a$ in wikiproof's definition is the first one specialized to $(X,\le)=(S,\le)$, $C=S$, $x=a$.

Comment: Note the second is not a definition of "initial segment". It is a definition of "initial segment of a well-ordered set determined by an element."